What are $w,x,y,z$ electronic transitions? How are they classified?
This paper's abstract mentions transitions $(x,y,z)$ and mentions another paper which talk about $w$ transitions in He-like Ti ions. The papers have diagrams which clearly show what these transitions are for that particular ion, but I would like to know why these names are used. What properties of an electronic transition are taken into account when assigning these letters to a particular transition?
